# One computer, switch between four monitors?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, kvm-switch

I don't have a powered standing desk - instead I have a fixed standing desk next to a regular desk. I currently have two monitors on the standing desk attached to the computer. I'd like to add another two monitors which would be on the sitting desk, then have a "switch" that swaps where the video is displayed between the monitors on the standing desk and those at the sitting desk.

Right now I just use the laptop's own screen when I'm not at the standing desk - but working with one monitor is torture after you've used two.

I know there are numerous solutions for using a single KVM with multiple computers - but what about multiple monitors with a single computer?

Comment: Which ports are you using for the current 2 monitors? VGA, HDMI, DVI, or Display Port?

Comment: One DVI, one VGA.

Comment: I have a setup like that. Two monitors to splitter 1, Another two to splitter 2; I then unplug splitter 1 manually from the video card and plug the other one in. Suboptimal. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll write the answer below momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I bought two Tripp Lite VGA Monitor Y Splitter cables ($14 each), one Cable Matters Gold Plated Mini DisplayPort to VGA Male to Female Adapter ($20), and one Tripp Lite DVI Splitter Cable ($12).

I found that DVI doesn't do splitting very well, so I ended up with one set of monitors being out of the VGA port via one of the Tripp Lite splitters.

The other set I connected by attaching the Cable Matters Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter and then piggybacking onto that the other Tripp Lite VGA splitter.

This served well enough for a while, then my wife bought me a sit/stand desk and now I only need the two. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a video splitter from a company like IOGear - http://www.iogear.com/video-splitter.htm

You might also be able to get away with a simple Y-cable, but due to the analog nature of VGA signals the quality of the output may decrease more than you find acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy VGA and DVI splitters. I found two cheap ones for you that will do work for your situation.

First one you need is a VGA splitter, [which can be found here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812423013) ($3.59).
The second splitter you need is the DVI, [which can be found here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200674) ($11.99).

Connect the male to the computer and connect the 2 VGA cables to the splitter and to the monitors. Same for the DVI, connect the make to the computer and connect the 2 DVI cables to the splitter and the other end to the monitors.

Let me know how it goes.